# BS3 Menu Toggle won't click parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

While in desktop view, my hover over links work in a sense. I hover over the parent, children display and we can go. However, in my structure I have it as:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".lower-navbar">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 class="visible-xs mobileHeader col-xs-9">Full Circle Solutions</h2>
    <button type="button col-xs-3>" class="navbar-toggle">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse lower-navbar nav-justified col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">    
    <ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav caps"><li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20 hovernav"><a href="http://optimumcard.dev.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-19 hovernav"><a href="http://optimumcard.dev.com/about/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu depth_0 subMenu">
            <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55 hovernav"><a href="http://optimumcard.dev.com/about/your-optimum-team/">Your Optimum Team</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-54 hovernav"><a href="http://optimumcard.dev.com/about/corporate-responsibility/">Corporate Responsibility</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rrL4p8np/)

With this is my Home About which has children Item 1, Item 2, Item 3. Now the items I can click on just fine but the parent, About, is not clickable at all. It gets even worse when I go down to moblie view or tablet view, I can click on and toggle them, but I can't click on the parent to open the page up.

Now, this is what i need help with and am acceptable with. The homepage, hover over, which I've tried with a display:block; ut the toggle doesn't work right. We tried some js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000,
        pause: "hover"
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var attr = $('.dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle');
        if (typeof attr == typeof undefined && attr == false) {
            if ($(window).width() > 767) {
                $('.dropdown-toggle').removeattr('data-toggle');
            }
        } else {
            if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
                $('.dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
            }
        }
    });

    $('.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
            location.assign($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    }
});
```

to get it to add the attributes at the screen sizes but to no avail.

What I am trying to find out is how to toggle the menu when in mobile/tablet view, click on the parent, and click on the parent in dekstop view.

Comment: Please post HTML, not PHP. Also, you seem to be missing a closing brace inside your `on()` function. Good formatting helps those things become more apparent.

Comment: Updated to HTML code. Sorry, it's wordpress.

As far as the `on()` it is closed at the end of the statement before the bracket.

Comment: Thanks. Did you try adding the missing brace? The console should've mentioned it in an error.

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: Updated OP to include new code.

Comment: Fiddle demo added. Maybe try to simplify your question to one point.